# I have a question when using the function. ```yum --downloadonly```

Tags: centos, dependencies, centos7, yum

Please excuse my poor English.

Currently, I am using redhat7 and CentOS7.

I have to install rpm files on a PC in the offline environment.
As you know, it's hard to manage dependency files in an offline environment.

However, the number of files downloaded through the `yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=.` command varies each time.

I looked into the cause.
The reason is that it does not download packages that are already installed on that PC.

I want to download every dependency file to prepare for every situation.(including installed files)

But I thought it would be foolish to delete all the packages on the PC.

When using the command, is there a way to download all the rpm files that the package requires, regardless of whether they are installed or not?

- I don't know if it's necessary, I'm using the command `yum-builddep PACKAGE_NAME --downloadonly --downloaddir=.`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [repotrack](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/repotrack.1.html).

It will allow you to download the package *and* its dependencies.

To install:

```
yum install yum-utils
```